# References in Latex overleaf starts from 13

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am using overleaf for editing my documents in Latex. However, the citation starts with 13 not from 1 . How to fix this ?

Comment: Do you use citations in captions and/or headlines? Please add a [mre] to your question which allows us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I replaced `\bibliographystyle` with `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` and it worked